# custom button images not applying

Tags: android

Hi im applying custom images to button on different states, for which i create an xml file in appliication drawable folder in which i define states of button and images like this

Btn_enter_cutom.xml

```
<item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_enter" />   
<item 
    android:state_pressed="true" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/btn_enter_pressed" />
```

and assign this xml file to background attribute of the button.
button's default image is btn_enter.png but when this button presses i want to apply btn_enter_presses.png,but when i pressed the button nothing will happens,is there any problem with the xml file please help me in this regards.thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A state list will always display the first matching line. Reverse your two items, since the first one acts as a default and prevents any further testing.